# Same Origin Policy: Why can't JS code make an HTTP request to its domain?

Tags: javascript, security, same-origin-policy, websecurity

#### Example

I have a site `http://example.com`.
This site uses a third-party JS code: `<script src="http://third.party/script.js"></script>`

The `http://third.party/script.js` contains the following code:

```js
console.log("self.origin", self.origin);
fetch("http://third.party/api");
```

When I open `http://example.com`, I get the following output in dev console:

```
self.origin http://example.com

Access to fetch at 'http://third.party/api' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The third party script tried to load data from the third-party API, but it failed. 
Why did it fail?

The third party script and API have the same domain name (origin). 
Should it be allowed by Same Origin Policy?

Comment: The message is very clear: *"Access to fetch at 'http://third.party/api' from origin 'http://example.com'"* so its NOT the same origin. JS can be manipulated even being loaded from third party origins, so its not always safe to presume that. If you control that third party domain, add a rule to accept your origin, otherwise, the api should have a jsonp api endpoint for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin is determined by the URL of the webpage the JavaScript is loaded into, not the URL of the JS file itself.